# Firebase analytics: send event only once

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

How can I send an event only once to Firebase?
For example, I want to send an event to Firebase when I open screen first time on the device.
An event should work like **first_open** event.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `SharedPreferences` here is an example

```
if (getSharedPreferences("config", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isFirstRun", true)) {
        // your code 
        getSharedPreferences("config", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply();
    }
```